# The function sortBy with a split

Tags: kotlin

I have this code :

```
fun main(args:Array<String>){
   var a = "eat,animal,banana"
   var a1 = a.split(",")
   a1.sortBy{z.toCharArray().count() { z == 'a' } }
}
```

But the code does not work althought a1 is an ArrayList... So I don't understand why it does not work...

I get Error: `(19, 22) Kotlin: Unresolved reference: a1`

Could you help me please ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error points to [sortBy](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sort-by.html) because [split()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/split.html) returns a [List](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-list/index.html) and there is no [sortBy](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sort-by.html) method for a [List](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-list/index.html) object. 
You have to create a [MutableList](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-mutable-list/index.html) like this:

```
var a1 = a.split(",").toMutableList()
```

and then another error is the use of undefined `z` instead of the implicit parameter `it` inside the lambda, 
so change to this:

```
a1.sortBy{ it.toCharArray().count { it == 'a' } }
```

You could have used `z` if you defined it as the lambda parameter like this:

```
a1.sortBy{ z -> z.toCharArray().count { z -> z == 'a' } }
```

Answer (score 1):

`sortBy` orders the current list, so the list needs to be mutable (can change).
A normal list, isn't mutable, so that's why there's no `sortBy` method.

You could use the `sortedBy` instead, which returns a NEW list.

Making a new list:

```
val a = listOf("eat","animal","banana")
val newList = a.sortedBy { word -> word.count { letter -> letter == 'a' } }
```

or making the list mutable and reordering it:

```
val a = mutableListOf("eat","animal","banana")
a.sortBy { word -> word.count { letter -> letter == 'a' } }
```